# How to return the ID of the inserted row in Room database

Tags: android, insert, android-room, dao

I am inserting some rows in my Room database but I want to be able to access the ID of the inserted row.

How can I do it?

```
repo.insertMedication(new Medication(name, quant_aux, time));
```

### Repository insertMedicationMethod

```
  public void insertMedication(Medication medication){
        new InsertAsyncTask(medicationDB.getMedicationDao()).execute(medication);
    }
```

### DAO

```
 @Insert
    long[] insertMedication(Medication... medication);
```

Comment: From the given code snippets it looks fine. You should be getting ids in `long[]`  of `insertMedication` . Is there any problem with that not returning ids or being empty?